# Change timezone of mov files

Tags: files, date, timestamps

I forgot to set the correct timezone in my camera during a vacation and now the times are all off by 7 hours.

To correct this for the image files I used

```
exiv2 -a -07 adjust *.JPG
```

which changes the EXIF times by 7 hours and afterwards

```
exiv2 -T rename *.JPG
```

to set the files' timestamps from the exif time.

How do I achieve the same for MOV movie files? I am looking for a commandline solution as I have to adjust this in a large number of files.

`exiftool' shows me several times inside the mov file of which the most relevant should be:

> File Modification Date/Time
>
> File Inode Change Date/Time
>
> Modify Date
>
> Track Create Date
>
> Track Modify Date
>
> Create Date
>
> Date/Time Original

The first two (File Modification Date/Time
and File Inode Change Date/Time) are one hour ahead of the other times, which is perhaps due to the time zone setting:

> Time Zone: +01:00